# Wifi Adapter problems , Sometimes laptop recognizes wifi and sometimes doesnt even show it

Tags: drivers, wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

At the beginnin git was fine like for almost a month there was no problems with wifi . Most of the times on startup it doesnt even show that there is wifi , but sometimes whenever the wifi is working, it works for a few minutes and then  it shows a `connection Failed` and then nothing works ( even though it shows there is wifi , it cant detect any hotspots )

The only noticeable error that i had during installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Laptop was a `pci bus error` which i solved by adding `pcie=noaer` in the grub. But the fact that this was due to incompatibility of the hardware and OS  may be the reason of this whole problem.

The wifi was working well , for almost a month (upto now) but only having slight disconnections ( suddenly getting disconnected even when my hotspot was on , and then showing that there are no hotspots) however restarting would again make it work. But today it happened and I restarted in hopes of making it okay ( i know this is not a solution ) only to find out that now it cant even recognise my Wifi Driver.

https://ibb.co/QFBFNCp
https://ibb.co/8YGGn1J

What should I do now to totally solve this problem for the future?

Edit:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Some other problems i am facing are :
Although battery is charging (connected to wall) and the laptop hardware shows it is charging ( a light turns on if its charging) but the software doesnt show that its charging and tells me that battery is at 90%.

Edit: managed to get some more information

```
02:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```